# Unbound with forward zones

Tags: dns

In my network, I have a Unbound instance which works well for the global DNS. But all local requests are to be forwarded to another server (Dnsmasq) which holds the reverse and local addresses.

It quite often bugs.

First of all, I am not sure the status of the Dnsmasq : it is not a forward DNS : for its job, it knows the answers. But yet, it looks like unbound only accepts to work when Dnsmasq is declared as "forward". And then I think I have misconfigurated the local zones.

Here is the piece of Unbound's configuration to look at :

```
    unblock-lan-zones: yes
    insecure-lan-zones: yes

    local-zone: "22decembre.eu." nodefault
    local-zone: "22december.dk." transparent
    local-zone: "10.in-addr.arpa." transparent
    local-zone: "d.f.ip6.arpa." transparent
    local-zone: "2.2.0.0.6.1.0.2.0.0.d.f.ip6.arpa." transparent

    private-domain: 22decembre.eu
    private-domain: 22december.dk

    domain-insecure: 22decembre.eu
    domain-insecure: 22december.dk
    domain-insecure: "10.in-addr.arpa."
    domain-insecure: "2.2.0.0.6.1.0.2.0.0.d.f.ip6.arpa."

    forward-zone:
            name: "10.in-addr.arpa."
            forward-addr: fd00:2016:22:dec::1

    forward-zone:
            name: "22decembre.eu."
            forward-addr: fd00:2016:22:dec::1

    forward-zone:
            name: "22december.dk."
            forward-addr: fd00:2016:22:dec::1

    forward-zone:
            name: "2.2.0.0.6.1.0.2.0.0.d.f.ip6.arpa."
            forward-addr: fd00:2016:22:dec::1
```

When verifying conf', I get this :

```
     [1506975455] unbound-checkconf[89619:0] warning: duplicate local-zone
```